# How to make a JSP page NOT to forward to servlet without user's input?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Consider the following JSP :

```
<!-- Bank Application in JAVA -->
<!-- Updates : the DB now is using Hibernate for the SQL queries -->
<!-- 2014 version updates -->
<!-- This is a comment in JSP file   -->

<%@ page language="java" 
    contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Login Page - please enter your Username and Password</legend>
  <form action="loginPage"  > 

  <!-- note we use here a paragraph & font size -->
  <!-- Notice we use a Required field !!! -->

    <p style="font-size:15px">  <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span> Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br> </p>
    <p style="font-size:15px"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">*</span>  Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">

  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

Visual look :

[image]

How can I make the JSP to stay put and not forward to the `Login` servlet (to check the correctness of the input) , until the user had entered both `Username` and `Password` ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to avoid reloading the page?

Comment: @Happy: NO! I want to make the user to insert input , and not move to the servlet without any input !

Comment: Downvotes ? are you serious ?

Comment: Use javascript onsubmit and if empty fields stay there.

Comment: use JS for Form Validation and submission.. meaning the click of the submit button should trigger a js function which then submits to the servlet based on successful validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript in the `onclick` function of the login button to cancel the form submission, verify that the username and password fields are not empty, then submit the form

UPDATE:

In my code, I often use a `button` type instead of a `<input type=submit>` button.  Then I do basic validation through javascript.  Something like:

```
function checkFields(){
  var user = document.getElementById('username').value; 
  var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

  if (user == "" || pass == ""){
    alert("Username and Password required");
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

then my form would be something like:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="username"></input>
  <input type="password" id="password"></input>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="checkFields()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have not tested any of this, this is just off the top of my head. But that is about what I do.

EDIT:
You need to get the value of the username and password fields, not just the fields themselves, sorry for the typo

Comment: onsubmit, not onclick, is a submit object and the submit will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this, the simplest is probably to have the servlet check for the `username` and `password` parameters in the request and redirect back the the original JSP if they're missing (you should do this anyway, it's not just your page that can hit your servlet).

If you are adament that you don't what the request submitted until the username and password has been entered then you'll have to hook-up the onsubmit event on the form like this:

```
<form id="login" action="loginPage" onsubmit="checkUsernameAndPassword">
```

And then write the `checkUsernameAndPassword` method in JavaScript like this:

```
function checkUsernameAndPassword()
{
  var username = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
  var password = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;

  return !(username == null || username == '' || password == null || password == '')
}
```

This method will return `false` if either the `username` or `password` have not been set cancelling the submission.

Comment: I don't want the 1st choice you suggested . I want first to have both values and only THEN to forward to the servlet . Thanks , I'll try it .

Comment: @ron it's important that your servlet can handle the situation when the variables are missing because there's nothing stopping a user entering `http://yourserver/youapp/loginPage` in a browser.

Comment: It does , before posting this post when the servlet gets empty strings as the Username & Password , it forwards to another JSP that says that there has been a problem . 10x.